# @DBRef with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have a class called `Veiculo` and `Agencia`, in which the `Veiculo` possesses as a reference `Agencia`. When its not a list, **I can pass** the URI reference as well as the following [example](http://recursivechaos.com/blog/spring-data-mongodb-dbref/). But how I do when a list? I appreciate if someone can help me

Entities without getters and setters

Veiculo

```
@Document
public class Veiculo{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String nome;
    private String tipo;
    @DBRef
    List<Contato> contatos;

    @DBRef
    List<Agencia> agencias;

}
```

Agencia

```
@Document
public class Agencia {

    @Id
    String id;
    @NotNull
    String nome;

    @CreatedBy
    String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    String lastModifiedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    Date lastModified;
}
```

Veiculo Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "veiculos", path = "veiculos")
public interface VeiculoRepository extends MongoRepository<Veiculo, String> {
    Veiculo save(Veiculo veiculo);
    List<Veiculo> findAll();
}
```

Agencia Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "agencias", path = "agencias")
public interface AgenciaRepository extends MongoRepository<Agencia, String> {

    Agencia save(Agencia t);
    List<Agencia> findAll();
    Agencia findByNome(@Param("nome") String nome);
}
```

Curl

POST in /api/agencias

```
daniela@daniela-tars:~$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"nome": "Agencia"}' localhost:8181/api/agencias
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 01:58:40 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 01:58:40 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ada75044ae41ca763aa3b4
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 01:58:40 GMT

{
  "nome" : "Agencia",
  "createdBy" : "anonymousUser",
  "lastModifiedBy" : "anonymousUser",
  "createdAt" : "2015-07-21T01:58:40.021+0000",
  "lastModified" : "2015-07-21T01:58:40.021+0000",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ada75044ae41ca763aa3b4"
    }
  }
}
```

POST in /api/veiculos

```
daniela@daniela-tars:~$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"nome": "Veiculo", "tipo": "Tipo"}' localhost:8181/api/veiculosHTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 01:59:15 GMT

{
  "nome" : "Veiculo",
  "tipo" : "Tipo",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7"
    },
    "contatos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7/contatos"
    },
    "agencias" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7/agencias"
    }
  }
}
```

Association URI

```
    daniela@daniela-tars:~$ curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ada75044ae41ca763aa3b4" http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7/agencias
    HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: 0
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 02:00:13 GMT
    daniela@daniela-tars:~$ curl localhost:8181/api/veiculos
    {"timestamp":1437444045504,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException","message":"no db; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: no db","path":"/api/veiculos"}
daniela@daniela-tars:~$ curl localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7
    {"timestamp":1437444071205,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException","message":"no db; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: no db","path":"/api/veiculos/55ada77344ae41ca763aa3b7"}
```

Log

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: no
>   db; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: no db     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2011)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1841)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1654)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:613)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findOne(SimpleMongoRepository.java:119)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:452)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:437)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.findOne(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindOne(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindOne(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.doWithReferencedProperty(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:437)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:352)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:728)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: no db     at
>   com.mongodb.DBRefBase.fetch(DBRefBase.java:86)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.ReflectiveDBRefResolver.fetch(ReflectiveDBRefResolver.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.fetch(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:904)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:869)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolverCallback.resolve(DefaultDbRefResolverCallback.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver.resolveDbRef(DefaultDbRefResolver.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$2.doWithAssociation(MappingMongoConverter.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1837)
>     ... 88 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource serving `Veiculo` instances exposes links to an [association resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) for both `Contato` and `Agencia`. You can POST payloads with a media type `text/uri-list` to them to assign references to the `Veiculo`.

Comment: This happens when I make a get request in /veiculos,/veiculos/{id} and /veiculos/{id}/agencias/{id} : `{
  "timestamp": 1437414418319,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
  "message": "no db; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: no db",
  "path": "/api/veiculos/55ad30e8ccf29fbf6011411e/agencias"
}`

Comment: The problem was that it was the application was running Fongo, the mongoDB in memory